# replace email template default header and footer

Tags: magento2.4, email-templates

can I replace the header and footer by using block in this email template file?
I want to use something else that I created in (Content->Block)
Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override these template on your theme, so

```
app/design/frontend/YourVendor/yourtheme/Magento_Email/email/header_template.html
```

You can't directly use a block since here we have html template. But you can configure a block via layout.xml and call it on email template.

You can check for example the email layout of a new order where you can find something like

`{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}`

and if you search in the layout folder you'll find "sales_email_order_items.xml" with the block passed to the template.
In here you can call your static block.